# Rails date_select as single pulldown instead of three?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, forms

The current date_select form helper in Rails creates three pulldown menus for selecting month, date, and year for a date. Is there away to instead have a single pulldown with a list of dates?

For example, a list of the next 30 days from "Jan 1, 2011" to "Jan 30, 2011"?

Comment: I think you'd have to write you own helper.. shouldn't be too difficult. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a select/pulldown control, an alternative option is the [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).
Using that, you could do this:

Your date field:

```
<%= f.text_field :some_date %> # => presume that element id is some_date_id
```

You can add a drop down calendar to it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $( "#some_date_id" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is the way to go with this.  One suggestions to the code Zabba wrote - assign a specific class to the date field (eg :class=>"useDatePicker" and on document.onReady, do a $(".useDatePicker").datepicker().  I've found this to be a good way of assigning datepickers through the entire app without having to worry about IDs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a date_select_tag use a select_tag and provide it an array of dates.

```
select_tag "invoice_date", options_from_collection_for_select(@array_of_dates,:first,:first)
```

Not sure how you're using the form. Perhaps if you post that snippet, a more specific and correct answer can be provided.

If you need date_select to work differently, you need to override the helper and roll your own. If you just want a certain functionality in your app and not interested in changing Rails itself, go for the select_tag option.